# JDBC statement fails to delete row in specific MySql table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-delete, failover

I have a table, say `example1` and I'm using a jdbc statement to delete one of its rows. I have tried various methods, from `delete from example1 where id = 1` to `statement.addbatch(sql)` but it does not delete the row. If I execute the same sql statement in Toad for Mysql it's able to delete the row just fine.

Weird thing is that using jdbc I am able to delete rows from other tables just fine; it's just this one particular table giving me unexpected results.

There is nothing special about this table. It has a primary key and no constraints/foreign key relationships.

Also, this delete is a part of a transaction so auto-commit is set to `false` and once all records get updated/inserted/deleted then the commit is done. This does not seem to have any problem with any other table and all the updates/deletes/inserts are done just fine.

Permission-wise this table has same permission for the db user that any other table in the db.

Any ideas or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you confirmed the statement is getting triggered from java?

Comment: you tagged this failover but don't mention it in the post - why? and are you sure nothing else is inserting this record at the same time you delete it?

Comment: I had to tag it failover because there was no "failure" or "failed" tag and I don't have permissions to create new tags.

Comment: Can you post the table structure and the code you're using to execute the query, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting triggered from java"? could you please explain? I have debug statements + am also debugging within eclipse and see statement getting executed..the system.out.println also prints the query and the result int[] which has length of zero. There is nothing else that is inserting anything in this table. The enteries in this table do get inserted via a stored procedure which is called when user on the gui deletes something from a table..so basically, any delete in a different table will result in an entry in this table for that deleted record with info about that record.

Comment: code (simplyfying some stuff) [Code] if(ids != null && !ids.isEmpty())
   {
    String msg = "Total entries to Delete in example1: "+ids.size();
    
    System.out.println(msg) ;
    for (Integer param : ids )
    {
     String deleteQuery = somemethod();
     System.out.println("query added to batch: " + deleteQuery) ;
    }
    int[] counts = delStatement.executeBatch() ;
    handleWarnings(delStatement.getWarnings()) ;
    msg = "Total rows delete from table: "+counts.length;
    System.out.println(msg) ;
   }
  }
  catch (SQLException e)
  {... [/Code]

Comment: snicolas, it's an int type field. treating it string will throw exception.

Comment: Don't see call to stmt.addBatch(sqlString), in code snippet.

Comment: blob, I had to truncate the message to keep it short..but it's there. I've tried deleting even with the executeUpdate of statement but still no results.

Comment: Did you ever find the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on general logging on the database or profiling in the JDBC driver would show you what's actually going to the database:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Enable profiling of queries for Connector/J by adding this to your connection string: profileSQL=true

General Logging documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

There's also mk-query-digest for sniffing your network traffic and analyzing the results:
http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Let me try that.

Comment: I found the issue...it was my code bug. I was executing the delete on wrong connection...I needed to execute it on source connection but I was executing on target db connection and since those records don't exist in target it was not able to delete them. Joshua's links helped me re-evaluate my connection specific setting and I found out the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same situation

I remember there was a defnitely mistake in the query
Try to execute the query in the mysql sqlyog or any GUI and check if it works, i am 100% sure it wont work

then correct the query and check it

Comment: Like I said, I'm copy and pasting the query from system.out.println into toad for mysql and it works just fine. I mean how complicated a query like "delete from example1 where id = 1" can be? It would throw sqlexception if there is a syntax error...I'm even checking for SQLWarnings but nothing there.